# What would happen if I move my bash script program in /usr/bin?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Let's say I have a bash program named Egample.sh and I moved it in /usr/bin.
What would happen? What would it do to my program?

I don't know what would really happen. Some says putting my program in /usr/bin will make my program run by just typing the name of my program.
So instead of: $ bash egample.sh
It will run by just typing: $ egample.sh

However some people say I shouldn't do it. That's why I'm curious.

Comment: It will be in `/usr/bin` folder according to filesystem.

Comment: Then what would it do to my program?

Comment: What do you think would happen?  Something bad?  Basically, the worse that could happen is any user could invoke your script without giving the full path to it, if their `PATH` environment variable includes `/usr/bin` in it; which is extremely likely. Do you have security or safety concerns?  Does your script include a `rm -rf *` command?

Comment: Any *relative* paths it uses (for config or data files, or other scripts and executables it references) will fail.

Comment: I don't know what would really happen. Some says putting my program in /usr/bin will make my program run by just typing the name of my program. So instead of $ bash egample.sh it will run by just typing $ egample.sh However some people say I shouldn't do it. That's why I'm curious.

Comment: if that is the only purpose and you're the only user of that script, create `~/bin` directory and add that to Path, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131310/add-home-bin-to-path-for-a-single-user-in-debian-wheezy-with-lxde. Then move your file there.

Comment: Possibly interesting/related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389969/315749 (note that `/bin` VS `/usr/bin` is a different issue; they can be seen as equivalent in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation depends on which scripts are in the shell scripting file. For example; Yes, it is dangerous if there is a "delete all files in the directory" command in the `Egample.sh` file and you have granted `chmod + x` privilege.

```
rm *
```

The above command will delete all files in the directory where it is located.

If your goal is to run a `sh` snippet with just the filename, without entering `sh Egample.sh` then you can use the `PATH` feature.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/file/path
source ~/.bashrc
```

I recommend you to learn more about File System Hierarchy. Up-to-date information on the FHS standard is available at https://www.pathname.com/fhs/.

You can also create a `cron` and run `Egample.sh` periodically. Everything is files in Linux and there are many alternatives to doing something. In order to find a suitable alternative, the purpose must be fully explained.